# How to add data to site programmatically

Tags: development

Let me start by saying that I do not have too much experience with Sharepoint. We have an in house Sharepoint site that users can go and enter data (less than 10 fields) and run some reports on that data. All is good with this part, but I was asked to come up with a way to add data in an automated way to the site. This will only be done under certain scenarios. Most of the data entry will be done by users going to the site.

My question, is it possible to add data to a sharepoint site programmatically (c#)? If so, how do I accomplish this? Do I add data directly to the SQL server DB? How do I identify the tables that are used by the particular sharepoint site?

Thanks

Comment: In what format is your data coming?

Comment: So what is the format of data that you have ? You can always use powershell to extract data from csv and bulk upload it in sharepoint list . Do let me know the data format . I have done this couple of times using powershell .

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SQL directly. Bad idea anyways, but it specifically affects support from Microsoft. If you're looking for a light weight solution, go with PowerShell. If you're looking for something for end-users to use, then you can go c#/.NET.

Comment: +1 on this. Don't touch SQL. Use C# or even JavaScript (JSOM or REST API). There are several options available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very well possible to add the data to SharePoint site using C#.

Also there are other ways to add data to SharePoint programmatically. You can use either of the following:

1. C#
2. Javascript (REST/JSOM).
3. PowerShell

And yes, it is bad practice to add data directly to DB. So, You should avoid doing that.

Comment: does this answers your question?